# Number of previous logons to cache - is there any way to override the limit of 50?

Tags: windows, windows-7, domain, cache, credentials

The goal is to have over 100 users be able to log into an offline machine using their cached domain credentials.

Is there any way to override the limit? Do I have any other options for storing credentials?

OS: The machine in question is running Windows 7 on our Windows Active Directory.

Comment: [There's no *supported* way, so I have to strongly recommend against trying](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/172931).

Comment: @HopelessN00b are there any alternatives to using the cache? I wouldn't mind having to manually input it somewhere to store credentials for offline logins.

Comment: Make a local user on it ? Make them use owa or such if they happen to have a internet access later on. You will have to think on what they work and how to save that mostly (usb disk, etc..)

Answer (score 0):

The number of cached logons is enforced by the [default authentication package MSV1_0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378753.aspx) (`MSV1_0.DLL`) which uses aforementioned registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\Current Version\Winlogon\CachedLogonsCount`.

> Is there any way to override the limit?

- Patch MSV1_0.DLL.

  While this could be done, it requires assembly knowledge and forbidden by license terms.

> Do I have any other options for storing credentials?

- Use custom authentication package, such as [pGina](http://pgina.org):

  > pGina is a pluggable Open Source Credential Provider (and GINA)
  >   replacement. Plugins are written in managed code and allow for user
  >   authentication, session management and login time actions.

  You can combine [LDAP Plugin](http://pgina.org/docs/v3.1/ldap.html) with [Single User Plugin](http://pgina.org/docs/v3.1/single_user.html) to allow users to login locally if LDAP is not available. While this is not exactly what you've asked for, this is as close as you could get in my opinion.